# Laravel передача информации между сервисами через очередь

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5, rabbitmq

Вопрос такой, есть два микро-сервиса, один создает транзакцию и кидает в очередь (rabbitmq) второй сервис должен ее подхватить и обработать. Столкнулись с проблемой, что что бы передать объект через очередь, он должен быть именно инстансом jobs и что бы отработать в обработчике, должен быть полностью дублирован на двух сервисах. нельзя например просто положить json и получить его в обработчике. Вернее положить то можно, но вот как взять? Не покидает чувство, что я что то не так делаю, не верный подход к передаче информации что ли... Подскажите плиз, куда копать?
Laravel 5.6

Comment: вообще-то в rabbitmq отправляются строки, в том числе и сериализованный json. Не силен в ларавель, видимо там используется готовый класс, но можно написать свои обработчики отправки на php

Comment: Это запасной вариант. Ларавель имеет очень богатый функционал обработки очередей, и имея их писать пядом свое, выглядит велосипедом.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш идеал - для каждого микросервиса свой класс джоб с общими свойствами.
При этом на сервисе который ложит в очередь - методы которые отвечают за формирование сообщения в очереди. А на приемнике соотвественно методы которые отвечают за парсинг jsonа из очереди и выполнение.

Я так понял что Вас смущает дублированние классов, это обьясняется тем что разработчики laravel предполагали что ложить джобы и выполнять будет один и тот же инстанс laravel.

Что бы понять что не так, или как сделать лучше расскажите какая именно задача ложиться в очередь, т.е. какую задачу решает эта задача в очереди. Я попробую подумать как сделать это в более laravel стиле

Comment: Платежные транзакции и их обратотка на другом сервисе.вот я не могу смириться с мыслью что ларавель не умеет ередавать информацию между сервисами. А решение выглядит очень костыльным т.к. хранит одинаковый код в двух сервисах, и если в очередь улетел код, и в этот момент мы обновили приемника, то повисшие транзакции не обработаются из-за разницы кода. Ну дичь же, согласитесь) есть мысль принимать и ложить в другую очередь, ну или писать свой обработчик. Но мне кажется что есть способ какой то, либо я не так использую функционал

Comment: есть вам нужно сериализовать и десериализовать одинаковые данные, вполне логично, это это делает один и тот же код, и если разные сервисы, то он будет дублироваться. 

Я бы разносил по принципу: джоб приемник - джоб передатчик,каждый на своем сервисе, и у них будут по идее чуть разные методы. У меня было что-то подобное на symfony, там просто запаковывали в json кидали в очередь, а распаковкой занимался другой класс который уже делал действия которые должны делаться на этом этапе конвеера. Дубляж кода в некоторой мере присудствовал, но, примерно, в пределах 15 строк.